# Is my translation of “forget death” good?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

So I translated *forget death* to Latin, *obliviscere mortem*.

Is it somewhat accurate?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What meaning did you want to convey with the phrase? Did you want to tell someone that they should forget death? Is it the personification of death, or just dying more generally?

Answer (score 3):

Yep. *Obliviscere* is the single imperative of *oblivisci*, and means 'to forget.' It generally takes a genitive or an accusative, although it is much more common with a genitive. If you wanted to express it with a genitive, you would say *obliviscere mortis*.

This is also said to a single person. For multiple people, don't forget you would need a plural verb: *obliviscimini* would be the standard form.

Comment: Cf. Cic. 1. Cat. 3, 6: *Muta iam istam mentem, mihi crede, obliviscere caedis atque incendiorum.*